# Asking for help to add a link counter (txt file) to php redirect link code

Tags: php, redirect, counter

Im asking for help to add a counter for my link redirect code.

The link redirect code looks like this:

```
<?

$id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$_GET['id']);

$x[101] = "http://www.ebay.com";
$x[102] = "http://www.google.com";
$x[103] = "http://wikileaks.org";
$x[104] = "http://potato.com";

if (isset($x[$id])){}
    else {
     die (header("Location: http://www.google.com"));}

header("Location: $x[$id]");
exit;
?>
```

That code lies in a file called link.php, and then I use links like www.mysite.com/links.php?id=103 . When someone clicks that link the code will direct them to http://wikileaks.org.

Now what im looking for is to count the hits for the different links 101 to 104 without using mysql.

Maybe something like this?
http://www.stevedawson.com/scripts/text-counter.php

```
<?php

    if (file_exists('count_file.txt')) 
    {
        $fil = fopen('count_file.txt', r);
        $dat = fread($fil, filesize('count_file.txt')); 
        echo $dat+1;
        fclose($fil);
        $fil = fopen('count_file.txt', w);
        fwrite($fil, $dat+1);
    }

    else
    {
        $fil = fopen('count_file.txt', w);
        fwrite($fil, 1);
        echo '1';
        fclose($fil);
    }
?>
```

I have no idea how to add it to my redirect code, and also hopefully make it work for all the links. Counting each link, and hopefully not creating a 100 different text files, as the real site has lots more links than my example code above. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to count how many redirects to each web, or how many in total? If it is hoy many in total the second snippet you added should work. If you want how many for each link, you should have as many txt files as posible links, using that same code.

Comment: Id like to count each link, how many times it redirected.
Hopefully without 100 text files, the one im using for my site has plenty of links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding it to an array, increment it and serialize the array to a file?

```
<?php
$id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$_GET['id']);

$x[101] = "http://www.ebay.com";
$x[102] = "http://www.google.com";
$x[103] = "http://wikileaks.org";
$x[104] = "http://potato.com";

// Open and lock file
$filename = 'count_file.dat';
$fil  = fopen($filename, 'c+');
while(!flock($fil, LOCK_EX)) 
    usleep(rand(1, 10000));

// Read data    
$dat = unserialize( fread($fil, filesize($filename) ) );
if ( !is_array( $dat ) )
    $dat = array();

// Count
if ( isset($dat[$id]) )
    $dat[$id]++;
else
    $dat[$id] = 1;

// Write and unlock file
fseek( $fil, 0 );
fwrite($fil, serialize($dat));
fflush($fil);
flock($fil, LOCK_UN);
fclose( $fil );

if (isset($x[$id])) {
    header("Location: $x[$id]");
} else {
     header("Location: http://www.google.com");
}

exit;

// Count hits
foreach( $x as $k => $v )
{
    if( $dat[$k] > 0 )
        echo 'Site ' . $v . ' has ' . $dat[$k] . ' hits!' . "<br>\n";
    else
        echo 'Site ' . $v . ' has no hits!' . "<br>\n";
}
?>
```

I have added locking, so two instances can not read/write to the same file at the same time, giving a corrupt file!

**Final Edit** Working version which saves hits into an array, serializes them to a single file and reads the array back next time. Also a hits display example at the end. Simplified version!

Comment: aww didnt work. used it for link 103 two times it said
a:1:{i:103;i:1;} after the first and second time. Then also for link 102, it changed into a:1:{i:102;i:1;}
but still remaind just one line in the file

Comment: Thanks for trying but the dat file only saids a:1:{i:103;i:1;} And the only thing chainging is the number part (103), it changes to the last link  that was used.

Comment: Sorry had to go for a while, but I have simplified the code and updated it so it is fully functional!

Comment: Great. Not sure how you intended the echo "counting" after the redirect, but i got it working on a seperate file dedicated to displaying the hits.
Stort tack Hasse :)

Comment: Count hits was just an example! You need to read the file, add the original array ($x) and display the stuff. I commented out the header end exit and got a nice debug output. This type of "file storage" does not scale well, so use it for small websites only. Remove the data file to reset the counters! Vassego ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just add it. What is the problem?

```
<?php

$id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$_GET['id']);

$x[101] = "http://www.ebay.com";
$x[102] = "http://www.google.com";
$x[103] = "http://wikileaks.org";
$x[104] = "http://potato.com";

if (isset($x[$id])){
  $filename = 'count_file_'.$id.'.txt';
}else{
  $filename = 'count_file_default.txt';
}
if (file_exists($filename)) 
{
    $fil = fopen($filename, r);
    $dat = fread($fil, filesize($filename)); 
    fclose($fil);
    $fil = fopen($filename, w);
    fwrite($fil, $dat+1);
}
else
{
    $fil = fopen($filename, w);
    fwrite($fil, 1);
    fclose($fil);
}

if (isset($x[$id])){}
    else {
     die (header("Location: http://www.google.com"));}

header("Location: $x[$id]");
exit;
?>
```

EDIT: I just saw you don't want to have as many text files. Maybe your best choice would be to store it in a database. Or maybe store json in your txt file, read it, modify it, and write it again.

Comment: Im looking to count each link, not the total.

Comment: Check it up now. This way you will have one counting file for each link, and one default in case none of those links is the one being redirected to.

Comment: As I said, you can write json on a single txt file. But you would need to get familiarized with it.